# Python - h2o: How to specifiy column types correctly?

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to import a pandas dataframe into a h2o frame and specify the column types that I want. The problem is am eventually trying to do an .rbind() with two datasets, but sometimes depending on the values of certain columns h2o will force them to either real or int, and then they cant perform .rbind() because the column types are different. I want to make sure I can get two different datasets with the same column types so these failures done happen.

Reproducible example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import h2o

my_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,0,0,1],
                       'b':[1,0,.5,.2,0]})

my_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[.5,.8,0,0,1],
                       'b':[1,0,.5,.2,0]})

h2o.init()
my_h2o1 = h2o.H2OFrame(my_df1)
my_h2o2 = h2o.H2OFrame(my_df2)

my_h2o1.rbind(my_h2o2)  ### This fails

### try to manually specify the column names and types
col_names = [k for k in my_h2o1.types.keys()]
col_types = [v for v in my_h2o1.types.values()]

my_h2o3 = h2o.H2OFrame(my_df2,column_names=col_names, column_types=col_types)

my_h2o1.types.values() == my_h2o3.types.values()

my_h2o1.rbind(my_h2o3)  ### This fails still
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting the column type after you've converted it into an H2OFrame

```
# check types
In [38]: my_h2o1.types
Out[38]: {'a': 'int', 'b': 'real'}

In [39]: my_h2o2.types
Out[39]: {'a': 'real', 'b': 'real'}
```

Since we need `my_h2o1['a']` to be type real (since you will have a mix of reals and integers once you rbind the columns). We can use `asnumeric()`.

`my_h2o1['a'] = my_h2o1['a'].asnumeric()`

Once we have matching types we can use the `rbind` method

`my_h2o1.rbind(my_h2o2)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was aware of this fix on a case by case basis, but I was hoping to be able to set all the column types upfront on large datasets before I knew about any future issues that might pop up. I ended up just making a loop that goes through my_h2o1.types.items() and looking for any 'int' data types and converting them into .asnumeric(). I still think it would be nice if the column_types argument in H2OFrame worked, but this helps as a work around.

Comment: I included your issue in the comments of this jira ticket (https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5166) if you'd like to track it that will hopefully solve upfront specification of column types.